# CodeIgniter form validation, dynamically added fields

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

this is my form.

```
<div>
    <input type='text' name='name[1]'/>
    <input type='text' name='name[2]'/>
    <input type='text' name='name[3]'/>
</div>
<div>
    <input type='text' name='email[1]'/>
    <input type='text' name='email[2]'/>
    <input type='text' name='email[3]'/>
</div>
```

this is my `codeigniter` code.

```
$validations = array();
$validations['name'] = array(
    'field' => 'name',
    'label' => 'Support Name',
    'rules' => 'required',
);
$validations['email'] = array(
    'field' => 'email',
    'label' => 'Email address',
    'rules' => 'required|valid_email',
);
$this->form_validation->set_rules($validations);
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

}else{

}
```

but every time the validation is false how can i create validation.

please help.

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#arraysasfields

Comment: @user574632 i write same rules as you give me link. please check but it's return false. why it's return false i don't know please help.

Comment: it is not the same, you have forgot `[]` in field key. for eg `'field' => 'email[]'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the documentation states, the Form Validation class supports the use of arrays as field names. Consider this example:

```
$validations = array(
    array(
        'field' => 'name[]',
        'label' => 'Support Name',
        'rules' => 'required',
    ),
    array(
        'field' => 'email[]',
        'label' => 'Email Address',
        'rules' => 'required|valid_email',
    ),
);

$this->form_validation->set_rules($validations);
```

[Manual](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#arraysasfields)

Comment: hi i create as like you say but third record not applay any validation. working with 1 and 2.

Comment: @renishkhunt do you really need the index on the form? try to remove the index `name[1]` to just `name[]` and `email[]` on the forms, on your html example it should work fine even without these changes

Comment: yes you are write this is working thank you so much.